# How to allow input on bits of Microcontroller port

Tags: microcontroller

I'm trying to figure out this question:

> Write a line of code in C to **allow** input on bits 2 through 4 of port A.

I am familiar with writing code, I just don't understand the question. Can someone help me understand this?

This is for a 16-bit Thunderbird12 Microcontroller.

Comment: What is a "Thunderbird12 Microcontroller"? I'm not aware of any such architecture.

Comment: http://www.evbplus.com/ThunderBird12_9s12/ThunderBird12_9s12.html It's similar to the Freescale HCS12/9S12

Comment: They probably mean that you have to write a program which configures an I/O peripheral. In this case port A needs to be programmed in such a way that that bits 2 through 4 of the port are inputs.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!!